# How can i change step of speed to be 0.1 km/h

Tags: android, gps

I've created a simple application for measuring speed. Problem is that speed updates from ie. 0.0 km/m to 0.9 km/h and 1.8 km/h and so on. What can be done, so step is reduced to 0.1 km/h.

```
public void onGPSUpdate(Location location)
{
    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();
    speed = location.getSpeed();

    String speedString = "" + roundDecimal(convertSpeed(speed),2);
    String unitString = measurementUnitString(measurement_index);

    setSpeedText(R.id.info_message,speedString + " " + unitString);
}
```

Comment: I think this depends on how fast your onGPSUpdate is called and what value getSpeed() returns.. if it does return 0.9 and at the next update 1.8, I think this is the right value.. it would not make sense to show 1.0 if you are actually at a speed of 1.8. Or did getSpeed returns values between 0.9 and 1.8? Then I think you should post your convertSpeed method

Comment: may be misunderstood from the question? what do you want **exactly**? If you want the current speed, Wicked161089 is correct. If you want a value to interpolate the value in screen for the user not to see stair steps but a steep line, then maybe just that: Interpolate.

Comment: So to elaborate more, since afer 0.9 next value is 1.8, it will never display if a travel 1.4 km/h. Any ideas how to interpolate?

Comment: Should the speed info be display in real time? what do you want to make with the speed info: Show a text with the speed value? Describe you task please.

Comment: If you update so fast,nobody could read the display, since it will change multiple times a second. Only if you would use a simulation of an analog tachometer using a pointer, this would work,

Comment: I was able to understand why the step is 0.9 kmh. location.getSpeed() is in meters per second. And step in mps is 0.25. When you multiply speed in mps to get speed in kmh -> step is 0.9 kmh. My idea is to convert speed to min/km. I'll be using this app to measure running pace which is displayed in minutes per kilometer, so that measured pace is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Since your application seems to display a speed text value in real time, it is to late to interpolate.
You have to show the current speed value and if that jumped, this is a typical situatin for a digital device.

To interploate you would have delay the display of the text.
An easy solution would be to delay by 1s, and just do an linear interpolation with n steps.
n = (speedNew - speedOld / 0.1;
This gives the number of steps use in the interpolation.
The time delay between each step = 1/n seconds.

Once that works, and since 1s is to much delay when wanting to have the current speed, you coud try with 0,5s delay. This gives time to interploat.
But it gets more difficult.

Another more advanced solution is to estimate the current velocity, each tenth of a second.
You can measure the accelaration (m/(s*s)) and extrapolate asuming the vehicle does not change the acceleration for the next second.